# How to move generic typed parameter to an async move block?

Tags: generics, rust, async-await, lifetime

I'm trying to write something in Rust (which I love but don't have much experience yet) and found a hurdle I have no idea how to sort out.

My intention is to spawn an asynchronous task passing an initial state as parameter. The asynchronous task will take that value (it can keep ownership of it) and use it further. Thing is the initial value needs to be a generic. And I get an error complaining about the lifetime of `StateT` and I cannot let the compiler know that I want to move it / copy it to the async block.

```rust
async fn start<StateT>(initial_value: StateT) -> impl futures::Future
where
    StateT: Send,
{
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        process(initial_value);
    })
}
```

I tried making `StateT: Copy + Send + Sync`, etc but it doesn't like it. Only `'static` works but I guess that's not right (it's not a constant that I will pass, but some arbitrary struct).

The error message is:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `StateT` may not live long enough
 --> src/workflow2.rs:7:5
  |
7 | /     tokio::spawn(async move {
8 | |         process(initial_value);
9 | |     })
  | |______^ ...so that the type `StateT` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
  |
5 |     StateT: Send + 'static,
  |                  +++++++++
```

If I try passing an `i32` or a `String` instead of the generic it works just fine. So I guess I'm missing some trait bound for `StateT` that provides what's missing.

Comment: `'static` is the right thing here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084201/5397009 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66936290/5397009

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Only 'static works but I guess that's not right (it's not a constant that I will pass, but some arbitrary struct).

This is [common Rust lifetime misconception #2](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program): `T: 'static` does not mean that `T` lives for the entire program, and even less that `T` is a constant. It only means that `T` is a fully self-contained type and that it doesn't borrow any other data. So `StateT: 'static` is the right thing to do here:

```
async fn start<StateT>(initial_value: StateT) -> impl futures::Future
where
    StateT: Send + 'static,
{
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        process(initial_value);
    })
}
```

Comment: It's not that it doesn't contain any references, it's that it doesn't contain any non-static references.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! You taught me some important Rust concept today!